# In my facebook wall not displayed the my share

Tags: php, facebook, kohana

I share the site on facebook means the my facebook wall don't show the posted wall. Can you advise me to solved ?

`$fb_access_token = $this->session->get("fb_access_token");`

```
$fb_user_id=$this->session->get("fb_user_id");
        $redirect_url = URL_BASE."socialnetwork/facebookshare";
        if(!$fb_access_token){
            $code=arr::get($_REQUEST,'code');
            if($code){
                $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FB_APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_url."&client_secret=".FB_APP_SECRET."&code=".$code; 
                $access_token = $this->curl_function($token_url);
                $FBtoken = str_replace("access_token=","", $access_token);
                $FBtoken = explode("&expires=", $FBtoken);
                    if(isset($FBtoken[0])){
                        $profile_data_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$FBtoken[0];
                        $Profile_data = json_decode($this->curl_function($profile_data_url));

                            if(isset($Profile_data->error)){
                                echo $this->Lang["PROB_FB_CONNECT"]; exit;
                            }
                            else{
                                $this->session->set("fb_access_token",$FBtoken[0]);
                                $this->session->set("fb_user_id",$Profile_data->id);
                                return $FBtoken[0].'|'.$Profile_data->id;
                            }
                    }
                    else{
                        Message::error(__('sorry_not_shared_accesstoken'));
                        $this->url->redirect('users/dashboard');
                    }
                Message::error(__('sorry_not_shared_accesstoken'));
                $this->url->redirect('users/dashboard');
            }
            else{
                $this->request->redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".FB_APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($redirect_url)."&scope=email,publish_actions");
                die();
            }
        }
        else{ 
            $fb_access_token = $this->session->get("fb_access_token");
            $fb_user_id=$this->session->get("fb_user_id");
            return $fb_access_token.'|'.$fb_user_id;
         }
```

This is my share code

```
$post_arg = array("access_token" => $fb_access_token, 'message'=>'Test Message', "id" => $fb_user_id,'description' =>$this->metadescription,'site_link'=>URL_BASE,'caption' =>$this->title,'picture' =>$logo, "method" => "post");

            if($fb_access_token=="" || $fb_user_id==""){
                Message::error(__('sorry_not_shared_accesstoken'));
                $this->url->redirect('users/dashboard');
            }

            $share=$this->fb_curl_function("https://graph.facebook.com/feed", "POST", $post_arg);
```

Comment: Are you getting any log message with some code or something...

Also you havent requested the permissions....

Comment: And also, is your app public yet? (Top of Status&Review tab.)